# How to extract the string between two "/" characters

Tags: java

So I'm trying to extract the strings between the / delimiters of the url. This has proven to be a bit hard for me as Java does not accept "/" as a char.

```
String temp = "svn+ssh://xxxxxx.net/var/lib/webprojects/xxx/xxx/WebContent/images/Calendar_icon.png";
```

How could I get, from this `String : images , WebContent , etc...` ?

Comment: ‘*Java does not accept "/" as a char*’ What? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Jordi Note that `"/"` is a String and `'/'` is a char.

Comment: @Jordi You might want to use `java.net.URI` and its `getPath()` to get just the path first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about splitting the string by `/` -

```
String[] parts = temp.split("/");
```

and accessing the relevant parts by their index positions.

Answer (score 3):

First, use a regex to remove what you don't want:

```
String temp = temp.replaceAll("^.*//xxxxxx.net","");
```

Then split it:

```
String[] parts = temp.split("/");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function. With this, you will have your `String` divide in an array of Strings by the positions of where "/" it's placed. So, for example, if you want to access to the url, in your case will be:

```
String split[] = temp.split("/"); //Here you have your String divide.
```

So, to access to the url (look that it is on the second position of the array (because in the first position it's `svn+ssh:`) you will have to do:

```
split[1];
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 2):

try with split function of string

```
String[] stringArray = temp.split("/");
```